# Android: Can I vibrate an Xbox 360 controller?

Tags: android, android-vibration

I added this method to a simple Android program to see if the connected Xbox 360 controllers had access to vibration:

```
private void getDeviceInfo(){

    int[] ids = InputDevice.getDeviceIds();
    appendText("#devs: "+ids.length);
    InputDevice dev;
    Vibrator vib;
    for(int id : ids){

        dev = InputDevice.getDevice(id);
        appendText("dev "+id);
        appendText("name: "+dev.getName());

        vib = dev.getVibrator();
        appendText("has vib: "+vib.hasVibrator());
        if(vib.hasVibrator()){
            vib.vibrate(1000);
        }

    }

}
```

The Xbox controllers said false for vibration...
Is there any other way to get them to rumble?

Do any controllers support it?

Comment: hello, do you find any solution now? May I ask you what is your device? OS version and pad or phone?

Answer (score 0):

Evidently there's no built in functionality for that because you'd need to directly access the controller's driver.

[Source - Google](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/518958/how-to-make-a-controller-vibrate-using-android.html)

Comment: Too bad whatever drivers they are using don't support it. 
Maybe in future versions...

Comment: Here it is:

https://github.com/android/kernel_common/blob/android-3.4/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.c

TODO: get rumble working

Comment: Oh wait the support is there...
https://github.com/android/kernel_common/commit/b514d4f7c6506b696d7de6a4426d0886753e43c9#diff-6d0468d07e8b261854ebe7da113091d8
Now why can't android use it...